# How do I log errors when doing work on a node.js pg-boss queue job?

Tags: node.js

I have registered for the error event which will log the error.
I throw an error when the job is dequeued to be handled, but nothing appears in the log:

```
  const pgBoss = new PgBoss(options)
  pgBoss.on('error', error => console.log(error))
  await pgBoss.start()
  return pgBoss

  await pgBoss.work(queues.TEST, {}, async job => {
    queueLogger.info('Got job on test queue ' + new Date())
    throw Error('hello?')
  })
```

But maybe it is intentional that it cannot be logged - I can see the stack trace is persisted on the job table?

Answer (score 0):

I have added the code for the check errors.

```js
await pgBoss.work(queues.TEST, {}, async job => {
  console.info('Got job on test queue ' + new Date())
  const failedJob = await pgBoss.getJobById(job.id);
  if (failedJob.state === 'failed') {
    console.error('Error', failedJob.output['message']);
    throw Error(failedJob.output['message'])
  }
})
```